# How do I change the drag and drop threshold in Linux? (I'm using Gnome 3)

Tags: xorg, gnome, mouse, drag-and-drop

I'm not sure if it's a gnome setting or something deeper into the Linux OS, but I'd like to change the drag and drop threshold.

It happens too often on my clickable touchpad that I try clicking and it highlights text instead because I barely moved and it thinks I'm trying to drag. I need a threshold of like 5 pixels instead of what currently seems like 1 pixel.

Where can I configure this behavior?